# IIS SMTP service does not accept mail addresses with non-ascii domain name

Tags: email, iis-6, smtp

our IIS6 is running a smtp service.

This smpt throws the following exception if an email shall be send to an domain with an umlaut.

Exaple: mymail at mydomäne.de etc.

Doesn't the IIS support such email addresses?
What can I do about this?

Thank you!
Regards,
Uwe

Comment: I believe SMTP (as opposed to the DNS system) supports ONLY ASCII, hence the various encodings and MIME-types. It's a limitation of the protocol - I'm not sure of the workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email addresses need to be ASCII so really you need a domain for email without an umlaut.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address

There are plans to internationalize this in line with domain names, however this is not standardised yet and will continue to cause problems for some time as people update.

http://www.idnnews.com/?tag=non-ascii-email

Comment: thanks for that answer. But there are some users using emailadresses with non-ascii domains. how can I handle them? Is there a way to auto convert the domainname to the punycode equivalent?

Comment: you need to do that in your app, so it may be worth asking as another question on stack overflow